# Javascript / Ajax / PHP - Small issue driving me nuts

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I need some guidance, as im literally going crazy here.

Ive created code with php/js/ajax to check if email address exist when submitting.

So ive tested the ajax and the correct values are being returned. (checked via firebug)

```
Either 1 for user exists
or     2 for user doe not exist.
```

Now ive added an alert box to check the value and for some strange reason it always displays value 1!
(even though ajax value is 2)

```
    function validateForm() {
        var x3=document.forms["newuser"]["email"].value;

        //Check if username exists.
        $.post(
            "http://...check_user_exists.php",  
            {
                x3 : x3  //user email
            },

            function(data) {
                email_check = parseInt((data.email_exists),10);
            }
        );

        //Additional Checks      
        if (email_check = 1) {
            $("#form_status").fadeIn("slow");
            $("#form_status").text("Email Address Taken.");
            alert(email_check);
            return false;   
        }

        if (email_check = 2) {
            $("#form_status").fadeIn("slow");
            $("#form_status").text("Email ok.");
            alert(email_check);
            return true;    
        }

        more validation checks....
```

Hi all, and again... thank you for your kind guidance.
Firstly, I would like to apologize as i'm quite new to this...
I've moved forward slightly but stuck on the last part and not sure how to proceed.

So the form now validates the form elements and checks the email to see if it exists.
The only issue I have left is if the email value is ok, the form does not process.
Is there a way to set submit value to true with the ajax callback function?

```
<form name="newuser" id="form" method="post" action="do_new_user.php" onsubmit="return    validateForm()"> 

function validateForm()
{
var x=document.forms["newuser"]["name"].value;
var x2=document.forms["newuser"]["surname"].value;
var x3=document.forms["newuser"]["email"].value;
var x4=document.forms["newuser"]["password1"].value;
var x5=document.forms["newuser"]["password2"].value;

if (x==null || x=="") 
  {

  $("#form_status").fadeIn("slow");
  $("#form_status").text("Please enter your name.");
  return false;
  }

  //more validation.....

//Check if username exists.
$.post("http://ryangosden.com/breadcrumbs/check_user_exists.php",  
         {
            x3 : x3
         } , 

         function(data)
          { 

            var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);

            if (obj.email_exists == 1) 
              {   
                $("#form_status").fadeIn("slow");
                $("#form_status").text("Email Address Taken.");

            }  

            if (obj.email_exists == 2)   
              {   
            $("#form_status").fadeIn("slow");
                $("#form_status").text("Email ok.");
                validateForm(true);
              }  
});

return false;  

}
```

Thanks again all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The callback function is called asynchronously. Therefore you cannot call `validateForm()` in the way that you are expecting to, which contacts the server, parses the result, and returns `true` or `false`. What actually happens is that the `$post( ...` code runs, *but does not wait* for the response. Instead, it immediately continues through the code `if (email_check = 1) { ...` (which should have a `==` instead of `=`) without waiting for the POST response. Only later when the response is received is `email_check` actually set via the callback function, but the remainder of `validateForm()` has already completed.

Instead, whatever you intend to do with the return value, you must do in the callback function itself. That is, replace

```
function(data)
    { 
    email_check = parseInt((data.email_exists),10);
    });
```

with

```
function(data)
    { 
    email_check = parseInt((data.email_exists),10);
    alert("In callback: email_check = "+email_check);
    if (email_check == 1) {
        $("#form_status").fadeIn("slow");
        $("#form_status").text("Email Address Taken.");
    }

    if (email_check == 2) {
        $("#form_status").fadeIn("slow");
        $("#form_status").text("Email ok.");
    }
    });
```

Anything else you were doing with the return value of `validateForm()` should also go in the callback function.

Comment: Gentlemen thank you for your knowledge. Ive moved a little more but come into another issue is trying to validate everything in one function. I'll give it a go before asking for more advice. Thanks for clearing that up! Regards, ryan

Answer (score 5):

You are not comparing but assigning `1` to `email_check`

```
if (email_check = 1)
```

but should be

```
if (email_check == 1) 

= is an assignment operator
== is a comparison operator
=== is a strict comparison operator
```

Answer (score 1):

why you are assigning the value instead of comparing it.

= assigns the value

== compares the value

```
if (email_check = 1)
```

you should do this:

```
if (email_check == 1)
```

and

```
if (email_check == 2)
```

Comment: Thanks all for your kind help!